# WPF DataGrid row color by item property name

Tags: wpf, datagrid, attached-properties

I have this DataGridRow template (it's simplified):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" x:Key="DataGridRowStyle">        
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="OverlayBorder" Opacity="0.08">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,0" StartPoint="10,10"
                                                 MappingMode="Absolute" SpreadMethod="Repeat">
                                <GradientStop Color="{Binding EntityState, Converter={resources:EntityStateToColorConverter}}" Offset="0" />
                                <GradientStop Color="{Binding EntityState, Converter={resources:EntityStateToColorConverter}}" Offset="0.4" />
                                <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.4" />
                                <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                    </Border>
                    <Border x:Name="DGR_Border"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <DataGridCellsPresenter />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource DataGridRowBackgroundHover}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DataGridRowBackgroundSelected}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>                    
</Style>
```

And I have some class:

```
public class EntityWithState
{
    public EntityStateEnum EntityState { get; set; }
}
```

The template works fine with class `EntityWithState`. Look at this row

```
<GradientStop Color="{Binding EntityState, Converter={resources:EntityStateToColorConverter}}" Offset="0" />
```

depending on `EntityWithState.EntityState` DataGridRow sets gradient background.

But if I have another class:

```
public class EntityWithEntityWithState
{
    public EntityWithState EntityWithState { get; set; }
}
```

Our template must be:

```
<GradientStop Color="{Binding EntityWithState.EntityState, Converter={resources:EntityStateToColorConverter}}" Offset="0" />``
```

My question is how can I use same template for several classes?
I think Attached Propery helps me. For example:

```
<DataGrid UiExtensions:DataGrid.StatePropName="EntityWithState.EntityState">
...
</DataGrid>
```

But I do not know how to implement it. Or if there is another solution...

**UPDATE** (22.11.2017)

I could use

```
public class EntityWithEntityWithStateViewModel
{
    public EntityWithEntityWithState EntityWithEntityWithState { get; set; }
    public EntityStateEnum EntityState => EntityWithEntityWithState.EntityWithState.EntityState;
}
```

but I want do it without ViewModel access, only with XAML and UI

**UPDATE 2** (23.11.2017)

In otherwords I need something like `DisplayMemberPath` of `ComboBox` or `ListBox`

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how can I use same template for several classes?

Short answer: You can't.

You can't replace only the binding path and re-use the rest of the template I am afraid. A template is always defined "as a whole":

[WPF: Is there a way to override part of a ControlTemplate without redefining the whole style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570096/wpf-is-there-a-way-to-override-part-of-a-controltemplate-without-redefining-the/41570242#41570242)

So there is no way to do this in XAML. You might want to consider creating the templates programmatically:

[How generate custom columns for FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Datagrid))?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46522636/how-generate-custom-columns-for-frameworkelementfactorytypeofdatagrid/46523583#46523583)